# get facebook status

Tags: facebook

I'm looking for a good, simple PHP or JS function to get my latest Facebook status updates. Anyone have a good solution?

I had a JS script but simply stop working.

heres the code:
[view code](http://www.anamoura.com.pt/ajax-facebook.html)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the linked example I'm seeing an error: "Failed to load source for: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js"  Sounds like that CDN link for jQuery isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Facebook app, you can use it to generate an access token, and then you can just make a simple http request:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?access_token=2221230867|2.xxxxx.xxxxx`

When you create a FB app via https://www.facebook.com/developers there is a link to some sample PHP code. If you specify offline_access permissions, the access code will not automatically expire. see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody needs it I have a working example of this on mt blog http://dashasalo.com/2011/09/12/get-your-own-facebook-status/ Here is a modified example that uses the Facebook example

```php
// your app id from app settings page
$app_id = "11111111";
// your app secret
$app_secret = "sdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdf";
// url facebook will post data to
$my_url = "http://dashasalo.com/fbauth.php";

session_start();
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
  $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
  $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
    . $_SESSION['state'].'&scope=user_status,offline_access';

  echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
    . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

  $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
  $params = null;
  parse_str($response, $params);

  echo("Auth tocken =  " . $params['access_token']);
}
else {
  echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
}
```

If everything goes ok you will get your authentication token printed out. Copy it and paste into the following code:

```php
$appId = "11111111";
$appSecret = "sdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdf";
// auth tocken we have just printed out
$authToken = 'AAAAAABBBBBBBCCCCCCDDDDDDD';
// your facebook user id
$userId = '568864222';

$graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$userId."/statuses?limit=1&access_token=" . $authToken;

$statusMessage = json_decode(file_get_contents($graphUrl), true);
echo ($statusMessage['data'][0]['message']);
```

The code above will print out your latest status update. If you want to get the list of all your statuses just remove limit from the url.

```php
$graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$userId."/statuses?access_token=" . $authToken;
```